# Client copying from server to same server, without roundtrip?

Tags: .net, networking, network-shares, roundtrip

This is inspired by [Does File.Copy() from a network share to another share on the same machine copy the file over the network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555341/does-file-copy-from-a-network-share-to-another-share-on-the-same-machine-copy-t)

Is it possible, in .NET, for a client to get the server to copy a server file to a different location on the same server without round tripping the file via the client?

Is there any in-build support for this kind of operation, and if not, how would you go about enabling such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that it doesn't exist already, I'd enable it by installing new software on the remote machine. The software on the remote machine would do the copying, and I'd communicate (over the network) with that software from this machine. I expect I'd want the software on the remote machine to run as a service.

There may be builtin software that supports this already (I don't know what installed on the remote computer): for example, do you have IIS installed and running? WebDAV, for example, supports a COPY command.