# Does File.Copy() to a network share on the same machine copy the file over the network?

Tags: .net, windows, networking

Similar to question [555341](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555341), Would a `File.Copy()` (or `FileStream.Write()`, etc) travel over the network if the destination directory were a Windows file share that resides on the same machine.

**Example**

**MachineA** executes the following code:

`File.Copy(source, @"\\MachineA\SomeShare\DestinationLocation")`

Comment: why don't you unplug your network cable and test it out?

Comment: @GREnvoy - It looks like that question is about Machine B copying a file from Machine A to Machine A.  This one is about Machine A copying from itself to itself.

Comment: I noticed one answer, though, on GREnvoy's "duplicate" question that suggests using Wireshark to test, and that seems like a reasonable approach here as well.

Comment: So many questions. Is `File.Copy` optimizing the network out entirely? What network protocol handles the share? Does the operation go through any layers of the protocol stack? What might the next release of any of the software do?

Comment: Obviously if the server is the local host, the data won't travel across the physical network.  However, it will be passed through the SMB stack and might be passed through the TCP/IP protocol stack.  (The overhead of this will normally be minimal unless you're copying many small files.)